# How does blazor detect authorized / notautorized

Tags: c#, blazor

I am making a custom `AuthenticationStateProvider` to test in a Blazor app. I am worried that the new class won't have the same functionality as the AuthenticationStateProvider class because I'm not sure how AuthenticationStateProvider works. Below I posted my custom class. Could you please tell me if this is the accepted way of overrideing this class?

```
public class ServerAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    string UserId;
    string Password;
    bool IsAuthenticated = false;

    public void LoadUser(string _UserId, string _Password)
    {
        UserId = _UserId;
        Password = _Password;
    }

    public async Task LoadUserData()
    {
        var securityService = new SharedServiceLogic.Security();
        try
        {
            var passwordCheck = await securityService.ValidatePassword(UserId, Password);
            IsAuthenticated = passwordCheck == true ? true : false;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var userService = new UserService();

        var identity = IsAuthenticated
            ? new ClaimsIdentity(await userService.GetClaims(UserId))
            : new ClaimsIdentity();

        var result = new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not to worry... Did you see my answer to your previous question. It seems to me the only thing you took from it is worriedness...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Question:

> **How does blazor detect authorized / notautorized**

#### Answer:

This is one of the [constructors for ClaimsIdentity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Security_Claims_ClaimsIdentity__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Security_Claims_Claim__System_String_):

```
public ClaimsIdentity (
 System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Security.Claims.Claim> claims, 
 string authenticationType);
```

To [set as authenticated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.isauthenticated?view=netframework-4.8), just send a value to `authenticationType`, quoting docs:

> *IsAuthenticated*Note: When accessed, the value of the IsAuthenticated property is returned based on the value of the AuthenticationType property.

[AuthorizeView component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#authorizeview-component) asks for `IsAuthenticated`.

Look this code from [`CustomAuthStateProvider` sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#implement-a-custom-authenticationstateprovider):

```
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "mrfibuli"),
    }, "Fake authentication type");
```

For previous example, **`IsAuthenticated` will be true** because `ClaimsIdentity` constructor has `"Fake authentication type"` for `authenticationType` parameter.

**Summarizing**

If you create your identity **including** `authenticationType` parameter the user is authenticated. If you create your identity **without** `authenticationType` parameter, the user is not authenticated.

```
    var userService = RequestMyUserService(user, password);

    var identity = userService.IsValidUser
        ? new ClaimsIdentity(
            new[] {new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "mrfibuli"),}, 
            "My Custom User Service")  // authenticated
        : new ClaimsIdentity();        // not authenticated

    ...
```

More info at [Claims-based authentication](https://andrewlock.net/introduction-to-authentication-with-asp-net-core/#claims-based-authentication) on Introduction to Authentication with ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Why do you repeat the question in your answer? Is this a new SO policy?

Comment: hi @UweKeim, because OP asked for _"Could you please tell me if this is the accepted way of overrideing this class?"_  but I answered about "_How does blazor detect authorized / notautorized_" (that covers the op question). This solve your question? Thanks about your comment.